# Running user-defined functions using Javascript's Function

Tags: javascript

I want to run user-defined functions in my Node server, and one possible solution is to store the sub-routine as a string, and pass it in to the Function constructor, along with the parameter, and get the result. Its definitely a very weird use-case, but I can't think of anything better.

Anyway, something like this:

```
var sum = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');

console.log(sum(2, 6));
// expected output: 8
```

Of course, the Function constructor does not have access to the local variables, which is great. However, what are the possible security risks when it comes to doing this? The ones I can immediately think of are infinite loops. I am not at all worried about performance issues, because that is not important in this context.

Any input would be greatly appreciated on this issue.

Comment: Couldn’t someone conceivably access `child_process.spawn` or `fs` and screw with your server pretty bad in this scenario?

Comment: @BenSteward how could you get `fs` or `child_process` if you can't access `require()`?

Comment: And why couldn’t you write `require('fs')` in the arbitrary function you send to his server?

Comment: @BenSteward because `require` is a local name on the module, it's not in the global namespace. You'll get a reference error.

Comment: Well how about that...TIL

Comment: You may be able to do something nefarious with `process.dlopen` -- not sure.

Comment: `process.mainModule.require('child_process').exec('echo pwned').stdout.pipe(process.stdout)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I don't want to test that code but what would it do to my server?

Comment: Nice @YuryTarabanko.

Comment: @darkhorse Nothing harmful. It logs "pwned" to console. It just shows your server will be vulnerable to command injection.